# spring hbase properties : where to specify apache config timeout?

Tags: java, spring, configuration, hbase

Where do I set properties like 'hbase.client.retries.number' when using hbase.version : 1.1.1

Using xml to configure spring. In my xml:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:webr/hbase.properties" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mine.xx" />

    <hdp:configuration id="hadoopConfiguration">
        fs.defaultFS=file:///usr/local/XX
    </hdp:configuration>

    <!-- configuration-ref="hadoopConfiguration" -->
    <hdp:hbase-configuration configuration-ref="hadoopConfiguration"
        zk-quorum="${hbase.zk.host}" zk-port="${hbase.zk.port}" />
```

But when I set (in webr/hbase.properties) :

```
hbase.client.retries.number=0
zookeeper.session.timeout=38000
zookeeper.recovery.retry=0
hbase.rpc.timeout=29000
zookeeper.recovery.retry=0
```

They do not get picked up (the program hangs for more than 3 minutes) after a scan is sent.

The hadoop install is on my lan.